Is the Windows 10 boot loader in system reserved partition the same as the one in the EFI partition?
If Windows 10 is installed on an MBR HDD, the installer creates a system reserved partition to store the boot loader. If Windows 10 is installed on a GPT HDD, the installer creates an EFI partition to store the boot loader. I wonder if the boot loaders are the same in the two cases. I'm about to change the system reserved partition to EFI partition so considering if I should just keep the boot loader there or make some modifications.

What do you mean by whether they are the same? Do you mean whether they are bit-by-bit identical, or perform similar functions, or could be used interchangeably? What is the problem you are actually trying to solve that this theoretical query is based on? Please note that Superuser requires practical questions, which usually means they're based on actual problems, and focusing on the actual problem is often a better question than the one based on assumptions you've made SINCE facing the actual problem.

@music2myear Added my motivations to this question.

So is your actual question whether you will need to do things after making the change in order for the OS to boot? Also, it seems like this should be an update to the other question you've asked recently, though, perhaps not as site rules require a single question per post.

@music2myear I'm just about to execute the scheme in your answer to my last question but find your answer was deleted, why? This question is related to my last question but I'm actually want to know more about the internals of the boot process.

That wasn't me, just FYI. I haven't commented on or answered your other question.

Interesting! Some valuable comments and answers to my questions just appear for a while and then disappear.

Two answers have been deleted for various reasons.

@music2myear - There are no deleted answers to this question are you referring to a different question or a comment “answer”?

OP has another question along a similar topic. They refer to this: "...in your answer to my last question but find your answer was deleted..."


It's always recommended to recreate the boot files (AFAIK, the same boot files can't be used)

Open an Admin Terminal: +R → Open: powershell → Ctrl+Shift+OK
Mount the EFI partition via DiskPart:
DiskPart

::# List volumes:
    Lis vol

::# Select EFI partition:
    Sel Vol <#>

::# Mount EFI partition:
    Assign Letter=Y

::# Exit DiskPart:
    Exit



Create boot files:

If booted Windows:
BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI


If booted to WinPE/WinRE:
::# C: is usually not the OS partition

::# EFI partition must be mounted prior to proceeding:
    ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
        MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
        Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

    ::# Create EFI boot structure:
        BootRec /FixBoot

        ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is OS partition):
            BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

    ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
        BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD





Remove the EFI partition's mount point:
DiskPart

  Sel Vol Y
  Remove
  Exit



Reboot and verify; if boot fails, boot to WinPE/WinRE:
# WinRE: Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt
# WinPE: Shift+F10 to open a terminal

  BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD

# Reboot, even if no Windows installations are found






Overview of Boot and UEFI
Boot Process:  


No, they're not the same – though they might share the same "core" code (e.g. BCD parsing, NTFS reading), but they expect different runtime environment from the firmware (that's what makes UEFI not the same thing as BIOS, in general!), not to mention even the CPU architecture being different (UEFI bootloaders already start in 64-bit mode, BIOS bootloaders work in 16-bit mode).
Finally, the configuration that the Windows boot manager uses to keep track of the main OS (stored in the BCD) is also somewhat different between the two platforms.
You should use bcdboot.exe to install the appropriate bootloader files and generate a new configuration; it's available on every Windows install CD or USB (press Shift-F10 for console).
C:\>  bcdboot c:\windows


Might be worth mentioning that there's the /f switch which allows you to specify which "variant" you want to install (and all is an option! which only makes sense for MBR drive though).
